# Recording audio with NAudio and writing to a file when microphone input goes silent

Tags: c#, audio-recording, naudio

I have these two functions written to record and write to a wave file using NAudio. I cannot find a tactic to stop the first function without executing the last line and going out of the local scope.

The **audio_Rec** method is called from the main function and **audioSource_DataAvailable** function executes when there is data buffered in the **WaveInEvent**. As I think, **audioSource_DataAvailable** function runs only within the scope of **audio_Rec** method and when the code comes to the last line of **audio_Rec** (below line),

```
Console.Write("Recording Starts...\n");
```

it goes out of the scope and next line of main function executes. *(main is not mentioned)*. I want a method to hold out the **audio_Rec** method while recording audio until recording is stopped under the given condition in **audioSource_DataAvailable** function.

***count*** and **summation** are public member variables.

**audio_Rec method**

```
    public void audio_Rec()
    {
        audioSource = new WaveInEvent();
        audioSource.DeviceNumber = 0;
        audioSource.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(16000, 16, 1);

        audioSource.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(audioSource_DataAvailable);
        waveFile = new WaveFileWriter(@"d:/dev/csharp/wspeechrec/new_wave.wav", audioSource.WaveFormat);

        audioSource.StartRecording();
        Console.Write("Recording Starts...\n");

        //Thread.Sleep(7000);
    }
```

**audioSource_DataAvailable function**

```
    void audioSource_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
    {
        count++;
        if (count%5 == 0)
        {
            if (summation < 150000) {
                audioSource.StopRecording();
                Console.Write("Recording Stopped!");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(count * 100 + "ms :"+summation);
            summation = 0;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(count+" "+summation);
        byte[] buf = new byte[e.BytesRecorded];
        buf = e.Buffer;
        int[] Ints = new int[e.BytesRecorded / 2]; 

        for(int i=0;i<buf.Length;i+=2)
        {
            Ints[i/2] = BitConverter.ToInt16(buf, i);
        }

        int[] newInts = Ints.Select(x => Math.Abs(x)).ToArray();
        summation = newInts.Sum();

        if (waveFile != null)
        {
            waveFile.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
            waveFile.Flush();
        }
    }
```

Free to disregard the algorithms in second function. They can be neglected.
Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

- Handle the `RecordingStopped` event from the NAudio wave device.
- Create an `Event` or `Semaphore` or some other synchronization primitive at the class level.
- When the `RecordingStopped` handler is triggered, kick the synchronization primitive.
- Before you main method exits, just do a `WaitOne()` on that primitive.

Your `StopRecording` call in the `DataAvailable` handler results in a call to the `Stopped` handler, which triggers the Semaphore, which then wakes up your main thread so that it can exit.

Example (I'm partial to Semaphores, so that's what I'm using):

```
using System.Threading;

Semaphore AudioSync = new Semaphore(0, int.MaxValue);

public void audio_Rec()
{
    audioSource = new WaveInEvent();
    audioSource.DeviceNumber = 0;
    audioSource.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(16000, 16, 1);

    // Register for the 'RecordingStopped' event.
    audioSource.PlaybackStopped += this.audioSource_PlaybackStopped;

    audioSource.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(audioSource_DataAvailable);
    waveFile = new WaveFileWriter(@"d:/dev/csharp/wspeechrec/new_wave.wav", audioSource.WaveFormat);

    audioSource.StartRecording();
    Console.Write("Recording Starts...\n");

    // Now just wait for the "PlaybackStopped" event handler to signal completion.
    AudioSync.WaitOne();   // <-------------------------------------
}
```

`Stopped` event handler:

```
void audioSource_PlaybackStopped( object sender, StoppedEventArgs e )
{
    // Wakes up the main thread.
    AudioSync.Release();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I figured out a way using a while loop. I just added a while(!flag) loop at the end of the last line (Console.Write("Recording Starts...\n");) which continuously check for "flag == true?". And I added "flag = true" after the "recording stopped" line. Now it runs smoothly.

Comment: can you please clarify your algorithm? where these numberal values are coming from? 

count % 5 == 0 and summation < 150000 , is there any specific reason for these values?